# Tracking ecommerce subscriptions through Google Analytics & PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics

I have a site that has a monthly subscription.

I would like to use Google Analytics to record these transactions. That's easy to do with their ecommerce functions, but my transactions are monthly. I could just say that each sale is worth the average I expect to make, but then I won't get useful statistics like "people from country x are more likely to cancel their subscription after the 2nd month", or "people over 45 continue the subscription for an average 3x longer than people under 45", etc.

So what I need is a way to retrieve and store Google's ID of the user and then push purchases to Google Analytics from server side, which Analytics would then count as a recurring purchase by that person.

I found this article that looks like its explaining what I want to do:
http://www.stumiller.me/implementing-google-analytics-measurement-protocol-in-php-and-wordpress/
However it's not completely clear. It seems to me that this is not going to match then up with the country, gender, age group, etc. and all the other data that Google has on that person.

So if I get the Google Analytics cookie of the user with:

```
function gaParseCookie() {
  if (isset($_COOKIE['_ga'])) {
    list($version,$domainDepth, $cid1, $cid2) = split('[\.]', $_COOKIE["_ga"],4);
    $contents = array('version' => $version, 'domainDepth' => $domainDepth, 'cid' => $cid1.'.'.$cid2);
    $cid = $contents['cid'];
  }
  else return false;
  return $cid;
}
```

Then I can just store this and later use it to push the recurring purchase server-side to Google? And that will give me all the metrics with demographics and everything already discovered about this user to plot against the sales value?

Answer (score 2):

Alasdair, that's an interesting question :)

First off, let me start with Universal Analaytics -- that's the way to go and Measurement Protocol (= MP) won't work with "regular" Analytics.

So I guess what you want to do is the following:

1. If a visitor converts, you will store the CliendID.
2. At the end of the month, you will run a batch of off-line transactions with a number of unique transactions.
3. You can pretty much set all the e-commerce related dimensions/metrics with MP, just make sure you use the correct ClientID.
4. Google Analytics will attribute the conversions to **last-known** campaign source/medium. I haven't done any testing on demographics data, but I believe it should work.

We have done some testing with our clients and **Universal Analytics account are accepting offline transactions** and correctly attributes the last know campaign source/medium etc.

You need to provide a correct ClientID and use it in the MP request. Make sure though that you use [getter function](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains#getClientId) and not your own cookie parser. Also, I would suggest storing it in custom dimension for all the users, it might come in handy later on.

If you use Google Tag Manager, you can do this easily with Custom JS Macro:

```
function(){
  var client = ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId');
  return client;

}
```

Sending off-line transactions with [WordPress/PHP and Measurement Protocol](http://www.stumiller.me/implementing-google-analytics-measurement-protocol-in-php-and-wordpress/) shouldn't be an issue.

Hope this helps.